# Using Nodelists to Change Background Color of Page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create two functions that will change the background color of my HTML page when the value of an input box (color selector) is changed.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function backgroundColor() {
  let bod = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  let bgc = document.getElementById('bgColor');

  bgc.addEventListener("change", function(){
    color(bod, bgColor.value);
  });
}

function color(node, color){
  for (let n of node){
    n.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

and the HTML:

`<p>Background Color: <input type="color" id="bgColor" value="#FFFFFF"/></p>`

I'm not sure how to format this, so sorry if it's unclear!

Comment: So what is `bgColor`? Is is supposed to be `bgc`? Where do you call `backgroundColor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the addEventListener callback has an event param which includes the input value on it so the function should be like this

```js
 bgc.addEventListener("change", function(event){
    bod.style.backgroundColor  = event.target.value;
  });
```

no need for the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of different things going wrong.

- The reference to `bgColor.value` should be `bgc.value`.
- You never call `backgroundColor()` so your listener never gets added.
- You are passing a single node to `color()` but then trying to iterate over it with a `for()` call.
- You are using `getElementsByTagName()` which isn't wrong, but unless you need the live reference to the element provided by [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) you should stick with `querySelector` or `getElementById` which both return a single `HTMLElement` or `querySelectorAll` which returns a static `NodeList`

```js
function backgroundColor() {
  let bod = document.querySelector('body');
  let bgc = document.getElementById('bgColor');

  bgc.addEventListener("change", function(){
    color(bod, bgc.value);
  });
}

function color(node, color){
  node.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

backgroundColor()
```

```html
<p>Background Color: <input type="color" id="bgColor" value="#FFFFFF"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way (with css variable)

```js
document.getElementById('bt-color')
        .addEventListener('change',function()
          {
          document.body.style.setProperty('--vColor', this.value)
          })
```

```css
body {
  --vColor : #ffffff;
  background-color: var(--vColor);
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="bt-color" value="#ffffff">
```